# Cannot get android studio emulator to run

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just set up Android Studio and when running it I'm prompted with selecting an emulator I get these screens. I'm not sure why it's not working and why I cannot set up an emulator. Any help would be great thanks. I'm totally lost with this one...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked with your internet connectivity as its clearly mentioned ?

Comment: Internet seems fine. I'm here after all :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Android -> SDK manager and download the missing Android SDK's before you try running the emulator

Comment: It's downloading now! so hopefully this works, big download so could be a while. thanks mate!

Comment: Good luck and Welcome to Android :)